# Write single mysql query for reports (order reports) using group by

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have table called orders and structure of the table is [image][image]

I want to get the following output [image].Don't bother about date(Jan 14) in above image. Explanation for above image is:

I want to get total orders belongs to different countries(based on SCCountry in the table),% of different order categories (based on OrderCategory ,which also explained in the above image).% ROO means return of originals (based on the ReturnOfOriginals in the table (Yes , No)).% of coupons used (based on the CouponName in the table (i.e.,!empty(CouponName))).

Comment: You want it in one query ?

Comment: if it is not possible in a single query, it would be great if anyone tell me that how I should follow steps in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by two fields :

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderId) AS total, SCCountry, OrderCategory FROM orders GROUP BY SCCountry, OrderCategory
```

For ROO :

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderId) AS total, SCCountry FROM orders WHERE ReturnOfOriginals='Yes' GROUP BY SCCountry
```

For Coupon :

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderId) AS total, SCCountry FROM orders WHERE CouponName IS NOT NULL GROUP BY SCCountry
```